# How to pass a function in material ui bottom sheet

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, material-ui

I have 2 material ui bottom sheets. I want to pass a function in the first bottom sheet. And I want to invoke that function when the second bottom sheet is opened from the first bottom sheet.

```
this._bottomSheet
        .open(ActionComponentAuditor, {
          data: {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            plant: this.plant,
            country: this.country,
          },
        })
        .afterDismissed()
        .subscribe((result) => {
          this.func;
        });
```

I want this.func to run whenever the 2nd bottom sheet is closed

Comment: It would be great if you can share a "visual" representation of your problem so the community can help. Also, I suggest showing all the code related to your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.